# Php form input and error manipulation using duplicate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I only use 3 fields here for simplicity, but it should apply to a larger form. I am trying to check if the form is submitted, validate input, display error message if input is missing or invalid and keep in the field what ever user has entered. I am using two arrays with same keys, so I can detect input and set correlating error for the same key.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><title>Test2</title></head>
<body> 

<?php

$input = array("name"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"");
$error = array("name"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

 foreach ($input as $key => &$value) {

  $value = test_input($_POST[$key]);
  $pregMatch = "\W";

  if ($key == "phone") {
   $pregMatch = "/^[0-9() ]*$/";
  }
  elseif ($key == "email") {
   $pregMatch = "/([.\-]+\@[.\-]+\.[.\-]+)/";
  }

  if (in_array($key, array("name", "phone", "email"))) {
   if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $error($key) = $key . " is required";   /* LINE 27 */
   }
  } /* end if in_array */

  if (!preg_match($pregMatch, $value)) {
   $error($key) = "Invalid " . $key;        /* LINE 32 */
  }

 } /* end foreach */
} /* end check if form is submitted */

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ;?>">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $input('name'); ?>"> /* LINE 49 */
    <span><?php echo $error('name'); ?></span> /* LINE 50 */

    <label for="phone"><span class="red">*</span>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $input('phone'); ?>">
    <span> <?php echo $error("phone"); ?></span>

    <label class="label" for="email"><span class="red">*</span>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $input('email'); ?>">
    <span><?php echo $error("email"); ?></span>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

There are 3 problems arising:

1 - Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ...public_html/test2.php on line 27. Same for line 32 in 27 is removed.

2 - If I comment out lines 27 and 32, the code will stop at line 49. By this I mean that only text "Name" will appear. Nothing after. No text field called 'name', no phone or email text and fields.

3 - If I comment out php code in line 49, I get: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...public_html/test2.php on line 50. This is caused by the php code on line 50.

NOTE: I've marked the lines in the code.

I'm new to php and I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Shouldn't line 27/32 be `$error[$key] = $key` instead of `$error($key) = $key`? And 49 -> `$input['name']`, 50 -> `$error['name']`...

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for a quick reply Sean. I thought that in php arrays are constructed with () instead of [] and that [] is new to php5. I'll try to change it and see what happens.

Comment: Building the array you use `()` -> `$array = array(1,2,3);`, but when you access an array value you use `[]` -> `$array[0]`/`$array[1]`. As of 5.4 you can also use `$array = [1,2,3]`, but you still use `$array[0]`/`$array[1]` to access the value. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: That worked a treat. Isn't it great when a solution turns out simple. Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access array keys/values you use square brackets. Regular brackets are for functions:

```
$error[$key] = $key . " is required";   /* LINE 27 */
```

Same for line 32. And further down, same issue:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $input['name']; ?>"> /* LINE 49 */
<span><?php echo $error['name']; ?></span> /* LINE 50 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using square brackets as `$error($key)`which must be changed to `$error[$key]`

The second problem is on the html section.

you are using like `<span><?php echo $error('name'); ?></span> /* LINE 50 */`

which must be changed to `<span><?php echo $error['name']; ?></span> /* LINE 50 */`

You are repeating the same error on `line 53` and `line 56`